# How do I define a variable across all modules without needing an import?

Tags: python

I have a situation (just for development purposes) where I would like to define a variable globally - not just module-global but everywhere, without requiring an `import` statement (or the `global` keyword). I understand this is typically a bad idea, but it's fine for my temporary application.

Comment: I know there are lots of questions about global variables on SO - I couldn't find this specific case anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
import builtins
builtins.__dict__['global_variable_name'] = 123
print(global_variable_name)
```